# How do I retrieve data that is within a specific date range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to retrieve data from within 60 days of a `created_at` date. Here are two columns:
`SomeValueColumn`, `created_at`. I only want data for each row of the `SomeValueColumn` WHERE the `created_at` date is within 60 days.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I can't seem to figure out the `where` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `INTERVAL` function:

```
SELECT SomeValueColumn, Created_At
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Created_At > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '60 days'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a where statement like this:

```
DATEADD(DAY,-60,GETDATE())
```

So your query will look like this:

```
SELECT SomeValueColumn, created_at FROM table WHERE DATEADD(DAY,-60,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the postgress tag, ignore this answer. Its for mssql